# Serial vectorial subtraction in Python or "subtractive convolution"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, convolution, least-squares

First of all, I would like to apologize for the unclear title of the question: the reason is I couldn't identify the mathematical process at work.

Here is the situation in a nutshell:

1. I have two vectors, f1 and f2, of different lengths.
2. I want to calculate the least square distance between f1 and f2, element wise.

Here is how I proceed,

```
import numpy as np

def distLstSq(f1,f2):
    "Return the least square distance between f1 and f2 per unit element"
    return np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(f1,f2)))/len(f1)

f1 = np.arange(100)
f2 = np.random.random_integers(1,100,5)

nBuf = len(f2)
dist = np.empty(len(f1)-nBuf)
for i in range(len(f1)-nBuf):
    temp = f1[i:i+nBuf]
    dist[i] = distLstSq(temp,f2)
```

However, due to the large vector f1 (generated from a file of 4MB), I was wondering whether there wasn't any more elegant pythonic solution, using less CPU resources, in less time. Possibly a sort of a "subtractive convolution" where f2 slides over f1, elementwise, with the subtraction operation at each step.

Thanks a lot for your input!

Bertrand

Comment: What's `distLstSqPoly`and  `poly`?

Comment: *"I have two vectors, f1 and f2,..."* but *"...distance between a and b"*.  I assumed `a` and `b` should be `f1` and `f2`.  Is that correct?  Also, a runnable MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated the post according to your remarks.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to point out that the number of terms in `dist` is not `len(f1)-nBuf` but `len(f1)-nBuf+1`. That's just how many ways the shorter vector fully overlaps with the longer one.

Ignoring the division by `len(f1)`, which is just scaling by a constant, you are calculating the following for each slice of f2:

[image: summation]

So I think you can reduce the number of operations with some pre-computation. And we can also use `np.convolve` to find the cross terms.

```
f1_squared = f1**2
f2_squared_sum = np.sum(f2**2)
nBuf = len(f2)
cross_terms = -2*np.convolve(f1, f2[::-1], "valid")
# reverse f2 to get what we want. 
# "valid" returns  where vectors completely overlap
squared_distance = [f2_squared_sum + np.sum(f1_squared[i:i+nBuf]) + cross_terms[i] 
                    for i in xrange(len(cross_terms))]
mean_squared_distance = np.array(squared_distance)/nBuf
```

Your version:

```
nBuf = len(f2)
dist = np.empty(len(f1)-nBuf+1)
for i in xrange(len(f1)-nBuf+1):
    temp = f1[i:i+nBuf]
    dist[i] = distLstSq(temp,f2)
```

Based on `timeit.timeit`, my version is 30-50% faster.

The performance can be improved further by optimizing `np.sum(f1_squared[i:i+nBuf])` since that involves repeated operations. There should be some divide and conquer way to do the sum.

Also I think [scipy.signal.fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) can be faster than `np.convolve` but this depends on the length of the shorter vector [(see here)](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ApplyFIRFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback: on the scale I am working with (f1 around 70000 and f2 around 300 in length respectively), the difference gives me 10-20% faster with your code.

Comment: Also, I think there is one caveat with your method: to avoid overflow (I am using 16 bit unsigned integers, I need to cast the functions as 32 bit. In your case, there are more casts to perform and with the scale I am working with (f1 around 70000 and f2 around 300 in length respectively), I reduce your speed by 50%. That is, if there is no other solution less consuming for the memory, I guess.

Comment: How do you deal with integer underflow if you are using unsigned integers? Since (x^2+y^2) >= 2xy, I can avoid underflow. Or do you mean both methods cast to 32-bit signed int?

Comment: My binary data is originally 16-bit unsigned int. But with the max value of 65535, the operation np.square creates an overflow. Besides, the np.subtract calls for a signed version. I then need to cast the arrays as 32-bit signed ints. I need to do it for f1 and f2, but you need to allocate space in the memory for f1_squared, f2_squared, cross_terms, squared_distance and mean_square_distance. So with the upscaling (the files are quite large), what we win in speed with your method is lost because of the multiple casting.